# Why my Kedro logging file keeps empty? Am I missing any step?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, kedro

I am using Kedro but I can't get my logging file to be used. I am following [the tutorial](https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/08_logging/01_logging.html). The log file was created but is still empty.

Steps done:

1. Configured logging

```
class ProjectContext(KedroContext):

    def _setup_logging(self) -> None:
        log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler(filename='logs/mypipeline.log', when='d', interval=1)
        f_format = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(funcName)s %(lineno)d %(message)s ')
        handler.setFormatter(f_format)
        log.addHandler(handler)
        log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

2. Use logging (in my nodes.py file)

```
import logging 
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)  
log.warning("Issue warning")  
log.info("Send information")
```

And after running the pipeline the log file is created but keeps empty.

Any advice?

Comment: It might be because the location `'logs/mypipeline.log'` is relative to your `run.py`, so maybe you are trying to find the logs at the wrong place? Could you check to see if there is any logs directory under `src/<your_python_package>`?

Comment: Is class `ProjectContext` in different file than ‘nodes.py’ ?

Comment: @LimH. , thank you but the file was created on the right place. I just dont get the messages.

Comment: @dragon2fly, yes, according to the tutorial, is at the entry point of my application (e.g., src/<package_name>/run.py).

Comment: Ok, problem solved! It was missing the logger definition on the logging.yml file! Thank you guys for your support!

Answer (score 2):

Ok, problem solved! It was missing the logger definition on the logging.yml file! Thank you guys for your support!